# ajax json send an image and other data to a remote server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a problem that I can not solve (it is probably also your case if you read this).
I would like to send JSON data to a remote server via AJAX. This data contains an image and a string:

```
{
    "question": "Your SquareOff Question", 
    "photo" : "Your photo" // optional
}
```

I need to send this JSON to "www.so-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v1/squareoffs?auth_token=qSJPySVk5yMsaAVE6mSu" where "qSJPySVk5yMsaAVE6mSu" is a token that I had previously ask for it and store in the $_SESSION, in a php side.

So I need to send this information to my php page before send it to the remote server. And here is my problem. I can receive the image in my php page, but not re-send it to the remote server.

I show you my code.

On the Html side, nothing special:

On the javascript page: 
I don't know and to send the image and the string in the same time so. (if you have a hint, it would be with pleasure but it is not my mane problem).

```
function upload_photo(){
    var photo = document.getElementById('photo');

    /* Create a FormData instance */
    var formData = new FormData();

    /* Add the file */ 
    formData.append('photo', photo.files[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'create_square.php');
    xhr.send(formData);

    /* Check the response status */
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200){
            create_square_xhr(); 
        }
    }
}


function create_square_xhr(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'create_square.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200){
           // response is a iframe who display my question and my image if I have 
           // send one. I display it.
       }
    };

    xhr.send('question=' + document.getElementById('question').value;
}

upload_photo();
```

And on my php page (create_square.php):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_POST['question']) && isset($_FILES['photo'])){

    $url = 'https://so-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v1/squareoffs?auth_token=' . $token;
    $data = array('question' => $_POST['question'], 'photo' => $_FILES['photo']);
    $data = json_encode($data);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    echo &result;

}
```

The response is an iframe who dispay my question and my photo if I have send one. 
But when I execute this code, there is no image displayed. 
I think the probleme is on the php page because I recive the $_FILES['photo'].

If you have any suggestion, I will be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: `echo &result;??`. This should be `echo $result;`.

Comment: You are doing two separate requests only sending one piece of information each time, so the first request the photo exists but the question doesn't, and on the second request vice versa. You never have all of the information needed at one time to execute your above php code.

Comment: So in essence `isset($_POST['question']) && isset($_FILES['photo'])` can never be true

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a check for errors by checking: $_FILES["photo"]["error"], which may tell you if there is an issue with the photo upload.

You also have to remember that when uploading photos with PHP that it is uploaded with a randomly generated name that you typically need to move to the final location before you do anything else with it.

This is typically what you need to do in order to have access to the photo once it has been uploaded.

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])) {
  echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
}
```